# Stripping Vowels in clojure

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to write a function to strip all ASCII vowels in Clojure. I am new to Clojure, and I'm having a little trouble with strings. For example the string `"hello world"` would return `"hll wrld"`. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can take advantage of the underlying functions on the string class for that.

```
user=> (.replaceAll "hello world" "[aeiou]" "")           
"hll wrld"
```

If that feels like cheating, you could turn the string into a seq, and then filter it with the complement of a set, and then turn that back into a string.

```
user=> (apply str (filter (complement #{\a \e \i \o \u}) (seq "hello world")))
"hll wrld"
```

Sets in clojure are also functions. `complement` takes a function and returns a function that returns the logical not of the original function.  It's equivalent to this. `apply` takes a function and a bunch of arguments and calls that function with those arguments (roughly speaking).

```
user=> (apply str (filter #(not (#{\a \e \i \o \u} %)) (seq "hello world")))
"hll wrld"
```

*edit*

One more...

```
user=> (apply str (re-seq #"[^aeiou]" "hello world"))
"hll wrld"
```

`#"[^aeiou]"` is a regex, and re-seq turns the matches into a seq. It's clojure-like and seems to perform well. I might try this one before dropping down to Java.  The ones that seq strings are quite a bit slower.

## Important Edit

There's one more way, and that is to use `clojure.string/replace`. This may be the best way given that it should work in either Clojure or Clojurescript.

e.g.

```
dev:cljs.user=> (require '[clojure.string :as str])
nil

dev:cljs.user=> (str/replace "hello world" #"[aeiou]" "")
"hll wrld"
```

Comment: @JoeCrawley Thanks for accepting the answer. I added one more just after that is probably the best. Good luck!

Comment: There is also `(remove pred ...)` for `(filter (complement pred) ...)`. And you don't have to call `seq` on the string. The sequence functions do that on your behalf.

Answer (score 8):

Bill is mostly right, but wrong enough to warrant this answer I think.

```
user=> (.replaceAll "hello world" "[aeiou]" "")           
"hll wrld"
```

This solution is perfectly acceptable. In fact, it's the best solution proposed. There is nothing wrong with dropping down to Java if the solution is the cleanest and fastest.

Another solution is, like he said, using sequence functions. However, his code is a little strange. Never use `filter` with `(not ..)` or `complement`. There is a function specifically for that, `remove`:

```
user> (apply str (remove #{\a \e \i \o \u} "hello world"))
"hll wrld"
```

You also don't have to call `seq` on the string. All of Clojure's seq functions will handle that for you.

His last solution is interesting, but I'd prefer the first one simply because it doesn't involve `(apply str ..)`.

Comment: Also, the downside of String/replaceAll is that it creates a new Pattern object every time. It's still faster than seqing the string though.

Comment: @Bill There is a version of replaceAll for Matchers as well. You could do it without creating a pattern object every time.

Comment: @Rayne Use clojure.string/replace, which takes a Pattern rather than a String.

Comment: @amalloy Yes, which uses the replaceAll method on a matcher.